# Detect if GWT *.nocache.js file loaded properly

Tags: javascript, http, gwt

In Javascript, what is the preferred way to validate if a GWT *.nocache.js file has loaded properly?

Background
My GWT application loads an *.nocache.js file within a simple shell .html page.

If a user visits the page with a stale auth cookie, the .html file loads perfectly from browser cache, but the *.nocache.js file fails to load, because the user needs a fresh auth token.
Since the .js file fails to load, it fails silently. The user sees a blank .html page with no indication that they need to refresh the page.

(note the particular failure here is that the .js file does not load due to wrong mime type. The auth layer handles stale auth cookies by redirecting to the login page. This page is a text/html document so the browser rejects loading it in a  tag. Assume for this question that I cannot change this behavior in the application :)

What's the best way to detect this circumstance and, for example, force a refresh of the page.

Note a hard refresh will force a fetch of the .html page from the server, which will be redirect to the login.
One approach would be to tell the browser to not cache the .html file, but I'd prefer another solution that lets the .html file be cached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you cannot change things in your application, I will answer just to your question.

You need some javascript in your `page.html` in order to check whether the gwt script has been loaded after a fixed time:

```
  <head>
      <script>
        setTimeout(function() {
          if (!document.getElementById("my_module_name")) {
              window.location.reload();
          }  
        }, 4000)
      </script>
      <script language="javascript" src="my_module_name.nocache.js"></script>
  </head>
```

In the case you use an iframe based linker (standard, xsiframe), the `.nocache.js` creates an iframe to load the appropriate permutation, and gives it the name of the module, so checking for the presence of that element after a while is enough to know whether the app was loaded.

You could also check for the presence of especial properties which gwt sets to the window like `window.__gwt_activeModules`

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a GWT app loads first, then you do authentication. You can use a split point, if you want, to load only the login page. Then, after the authentication is confirmed, you load the other parts of your app.

I have never seen a scenario where authentication is done before a page loads. Maybe you can explain why you did it this way.

As for your question, you need a JavaScript to detect if another JavaScript was successfully loaded, but this solution adds an unnecessary level of complexity.

Comment: Short answer: login is handled by a single SSO page, which is independent of the GWT app. The GWT app is just one of several in a corporate intranet.

Comment: I understand that part. I don't understand how you can load the HTML page but leave out one script. Which code makes that decision and where is this code executed?

Comment: The HTML page loads because the browser cached it. The nocache.js script is not cached, so loading it requires hitting the web server (which incurs the auth check).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your logic. It seems pretty straightforward to me: a user hits a single sign-on page. If authenticated, he is directed to the app. If a user hits the app directly (bookmark, etc.), check the token and reroute him to the sign-on page, if necessary. Use a JSP instead of HTML to check the token.

Comment: If the JSP page's output is cached by browsers, I would have the same problem. Sure, I coudl set the HTTP response headers on the HTML (or JSP file) so the file is never cached by browsers. The downside of this is that every time the user hits the site, an extra HTTP request is incurred. There's also a potential race condition, (albeit extremely unlikely), if the SSO cookie expires in between the HTTP request for the HTML/JSP page and HTTP request for the nocache.js script.

Comment: No, you won't. Browsers contact your server first, before they decide to pull the cached HTML.