# GWT : JS Error while redirecting to SSO auth page

Tags: redirect, caching, gwt, single-sign-on

My situation :

- An GWT application with a home page Application.html
- SSO authentication with a filter that redirects to an external auth page if the user is not connected (a token in session)
- A cache configuration like this :

  ```
  <head>
      ...
      <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
      <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store"/>
      <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"/>
      ...
  </head>
  ```

My problem :

- If cache is turned off on my browser (firefox), my application home page redirect properly on the external auth page : it works fine
- If cache is turned on, the browser try to get the GWT `myApp.nocache.js`, the respond of this GET request is `302 : Redirect` but the redirection fails (juste a white empty page displayed) because of a javascript error `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`. The script `myApp.nocache.js` is executed on the external page (my SSO authentication page) and fails

**I don't understand why it works when the browser cache is turned off and I cannot avoid the javascript execution when the navigator cache is enabled.**

Is someone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Well I solve my problem whith a dirty solution :

In my filter that checks the authentication, if I have to redirect to my external login page, I do a javascript redirection if the resource requested is javascript :

```
public void redirigeVersPortail(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, String uriPortail) throws IOException {
    if ((httpServletRequest != null) && (httpServletRequest.getRequestURI().contains(".js"))) {
        httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/javascript");
        httpServletResponse.getWriter().println("window.location = \"" + uriPortail + "\";");
    } else {
        httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(uriPortail);
    }
}
```

That works for me but if you have a better way to do the redirection properly in any case, I'll take it.

Others solutions are listed in this post : [Detect if GWT *.nocache.js file loaded properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861606/detect-if-gwt-nocache-js-file-loaded-properly)